# regular expression to identify certain number pattern

Tags: regex

I want to build a  regular expression to identify certain number pattern

The expressions required would be:

1)
6 numbers, starting with 00

2)
6 numbers, starting with 01

3)
8 numbers, starting with 200.

I started with ^\d{0,6}(.\d{00})?$ bit it did not work

How can it be done?

Comment: Try `^(?:0[01]\d{4}|200\d{5})$`

Comment: Or did you need three separate regexes?

Comment: Have you thought just extracting any 6- or 8-digit number then verify the rest with your programming language? Not everything has to be done in regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the alternation operator `|`. It takes either the pattern to the left or the pattern to the right. Hence, you end up with the following regular expression:

```
^(00\d{4}|01\d{4}|200\d{5})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(0[01][0-9]{4}|200[0-9]{5})$
```

Will match 0 followed by a 0 or 1 followed by 4 numbers 0-9 (total 6 digits), or it will match 200 followed by 5 digits (total 8 digits)

(Using character groups, due to the fact that the language was not specified, therefore, whether the special characters need extra escapes is unknown)

Comment: Can replace `[0-9]` with `\d` to get the digit character class.

Comment: The reason for me putting `[0-9]` was to make it implementation agnostic. `\d` can require extra escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: a number starting with either 200 and a number, 00 or 01 and 4 numbers

```
(200\d|00|01)\d{4}
```

Comment: Needs to be `200` followed by 5 digits or `00` or `01` followed by 4 digits.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid it is, check the regex

Comment: ah, yes, sorry, missed your `\d` in the middle there. Note though that as it stands this will also match partial strings - https://regexr.com/3ltp8